# Algorithm to find most efficient base to store large integer

Tags: algorithm, math, storage, bignum, radix

Very large integers are often [stored as variable-length arrays of digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum) in memory, as opposed to a straightforward binary representation as is the case with most primitive 'int' or 'long' types, as in Java or C. With this in mind, I would be interested to know algorithm(s) that can compute:

1. At *what count* an integer must reach before it becomes more efficient to store it as a BigInteger (or equivalent arbitrary-precision arithmetic construct) with a given radix for the integer's digits;
2. *Which radix* would be most efficient to store the digits of this large integer.

I have mentioned 'efficiency'; by this, I mean I am mainly concerned with the amount of *space* such a BigInteger would consume, though I would also be interested to hear any comments on processing speed or time complexity.

Comment: If you want space efficiency, the biggest radix that can be stored will do that. (Time is another thing entirely, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An integer should consume the least space if stored in a raw binary format (unless maybe it is a small integer and data type is way too wide for it - to store 1 in 128 bit `long long`). Storing differently does not save any memory and is used to make the work with such integers easier.

If byte by byte, this translates into 256'ecimal radix - 256 possible values, as much as the byte can hold.

Comment: I've seen suggestions to use `sqrt(max_native_int)` as base, to enable native multiplication of two digits without overflow.

Comment: I've also just looked at CPython's `long` implementation, and it doesn't use full words for digits either (uses 30 bit in a 32 bit uint, or 15 in an 16 bit uint).

Comment: One bit is required to encode the sign if you also need negative values!

Comment: But it's one bit per number, not one bit per digit.

Comment: @delnan: It is often desirable to use one bit less than `sqrt(max_native_int)` to do squaring efficiently. See the [libTom PDF](https://github.com/libtom/libtommath/blob/master/tommath.pdf) for a discussion on why.

Answer (score 0):

1. BigInt is never more efficient than one of the integer types directly supported by hardware. If you can use what's supported directly, use it.
2. What's supported by hardware most efficiently, likely a power of 2 or, often equivalently, binary.

Comment: Re 2: Are you talking about using base `2^wordsize`?

Comment: Any reasoning for that? As I already wrote in a comment on the other answer, I'm familiar with other approaches.